# Python Numpy - attach three arrays to form a matrix or 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is my simple of piece of code

Everything is a numpy array. I welcome manipulation using lists too.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [3,2,2,2,8]

c = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3','test4','test5']
```

expected Outcome:

```
d = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5; 
      3, 2, 2, 2, 8;
      'test1','test2', 'test3', 'test4','test5' ]
```

OR

```
 d = [ 1  3   'test1';
       2   2    'test2';
       3   2   'test3';
        4   2   'test4';
        5   8    'test5']
```

Comment: Are you interested in a particular string display, or a particular data structure (and behavior)?  There is a real difference.  A `;` is part of a display, not a data structure.

Comment: I am ok with any display as long as I can access the values whenever I want. Thank you or pointing about semicolon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adam's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39106248/6748857) using `numpy.concat` is also correct, but in terms of specifying the exact shape you are expecting — rows stacked vertically — you'll want to look at [numpy.vstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.vstack([a, b, c])
array([['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
       ['3', '2', '2', '2', '8'],
       ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']], 
        dtype='<U21')
```

There's a catch here either way you do it: since your separate arrays (`int64`, `int64`, `<U5`)  are all being put together, *the new array will automatically use the least restrictive type*, which in this case is the unicode type.

See also: `numpy.hstack`.

Comment: Could you tell me what do you mean by unicode type? When i print them I am printing them as strings.

Comment: This answer used Python3 where unicode is the default string type.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [concat method.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> b = np.array([[5, 6]])
>>> np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

Comment: Yes I checked it, I dont want the brackets in the final 3D array. And I am also facing problems with my c being a string. I believe it also says - that only length one arrays can be vonverted to python scalars - No clue what that means

Comment: The brackets are just there for printing purposes; it's a 3x2 matrix, no?

Comment: Should not it look something like this ?   [ 1, 2 ; 3,4 ; 5,6]. With semicolumn indicating difference between two rows. I believe if I have the square brackets, that particular row will have its own features - May be I am wrong - but thats what my understanding is

Comment: `numpy` does not use `;` to divide or display its dimensions.  It's normal 2d display looks a lot like a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Your `a`,`b`,`c` are lists; you'd have to use `np.array([1,2,3])` to get an array, and it will display as `[1 2 3]` (without the commas).

Simply creating a new list from those lists produces a list of lists

```
In [565]: d=[a,b,c]
In [566]: d
Out[566]: 
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [3, 2, 2, 2, 8],
 ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']]
```

and simply concatenating the lists produces one longer one

```
In [567]: a+b+c
Out[567]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 8, 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']
```

`numpy` arrays have problems containing both numbers and strings.  You have to make a 'structured array'.

The easiest way to combine these into one array is with a `fromarrays` utility function:

```
In [561]: x=np.rec.fromarrays(([1,2,3],[3,2,2],['test1','test2','test3']))
In [562]: x['f0']
Out[562]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [563]: x['f2']
Out[563]: 
array(['test1', 'test2', 'test3'], 
      dtype='<U5')

In [568]: x
Out[568]: 
rec.array([(1, 3, 'test1'), (2, 2, 'test2'), (3, 2, 'test3')], 
          dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<U5')])
```

or with a little editing of the display:

```
In [569]: print(x)
[(1, 3, 'test1') 
 (2, 2, 'test2') 
 (3, 2, 'test3')]
```

This is not a 2d array; it's 1d (here 3 elements) with 3 fields.

Perhaps the easiest way to format this array in a way that looks like your spec would be with a `csv` writer:

```
In [570]: np.savetxt('x.txt',x,fmt='%d  %d  %s;')
In [571]: cat x.txt     # shell command to display the file
1  3  test1;
2  2  test2;
3  2  test3;
```