# Numpy unicode to int

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, unicode

Using python 2.7 through Pycharm

I have a python code - which is very simple.

```
a = [2, 3, 4, 5]

b = [30,32,33,34]
c = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
a = np.asarray(a) # -- Similarly for b and c
```

I converted these lists to numpy array.

Then I did the following

```
d = np.transpose(np.vstack((a,b,c)))
```

Through which I got a 3D numpy array.

when I print d  I see a `u"` before each element, Which probably indicating unicode data type.

Now how can I access the columns of a,b and do some arithmetic operations on those values. Whenever I am trying to access a value and convert them to int -- it is saying `invalid literal for int() with base 10`.

All I need is read the first or second column -- do some arithmetic operations. First and second column values will be of `a` and `b`

Comment: Don't put non code in a code block. Don't put things in all caps. "Python" will already be in the title because the most popular tag is prepended to the question title. [edit] your question

Comment: If you want to keep the data type of `a, b, c`, it's better to use pandas data frame since numpy array can host only one data type.

Comment: @Daniel  I understand. But how would I convert them back to integer or decimal values?

Comment: @Psidom - I am completely illeterate about pandas data frame

Comment: Also the numbers are quoted, indicating that they are strings.  When you join an array of strings with an array of numbers, it creates an array with common dtype, here, (unicode) strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the last column is text, the other two columns are converted to text also. You can have only one type for one matrix. The solution would be a structured array:

```
a = [2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [30,32,33,34]
c = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
matrix = np.array(zip(a,b,c), dtype=[('a',int),('b',int),('c','S5')])
```

To access the values, you have to use the column name:

```
matrix['a'][2:4]
```

or

```
matrix[5]['b']
```

Comment: I cant access your values from the way you mentioned. If I say matrix[0] I get 2 , 30, test1 ---- I cant find a way where I can access the value 2 or 30

Comment: Perfect answer. IS there a possibility to append a new array say "d" = [ 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5] which is a float type

Comment: Nope, you have to recreate the matrix with `dtype=[('a',int),('b',int),('c','S5'), ('d', float)]

Comment: My use of `fromarrays` produces the same sort of structured array, http://stackoverflow.com/a/39106501/901925

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
```

> Now how can I access the columns of a,b and do some arithmetic
>   operations on those values.

```
a + b
```